# How to replace a nodes pcdata or text using pugixml

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I am looking for an elegant solution to replacing a nodes pcdata using pugixml (version 1.6). For example, iterating through a node set and updating the child value to something.

```
pugi::xpath_node_set nodes = document.select_nodes("//a");

for (auto it = nodes.begin(); it != nodes.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << "before : " << it->node().child_value() << std::endl;

    // SOME REPLACE GOES HERE

    std::cout << "after  : " << it->node().child_value() << std::endl;
}
```

I have used the:

```
it->node().append_child(pugi::node_pcdata).set_value("foo");
```

but as the name suggests it just appends the data but I can't find any functions along the lines of:

```
it->node().remove_child(pugi::node_pcdata);
```

Another note is that the attributes on the node are important and should remain unchanged.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean you want to delete the `node_pcdata`, or change it's value?

Comment: @Carlton I want to change it's value but as I couldn't find anything like replace_child I figured I would remove_child then append_child if this is unclear I will edit the question but the answer zeuxcg gave me is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xml_text object is made for this purpose (among others):

```
std::cout << "before : " << it->node().child_value() << std::endl;

it->node().text().set("contents");

std::cout << "after  : " << it->node().child_value() << std::endl;
```

Note that you can also use text() instead of child_value(), e.g.:

```
xml_text text = it->node().text();

std::cout << "before : " << text.get() << std::endl;

text.set("contents");

std::cout << "after  : " << text.get() << std::endl;
```

This page has more details: http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#access.text

Comment: Thanks very much that was exactly what I was looking for, must have missed the text() part of the documentation.